# trying to add quartz framework

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to add quartz framework but when I test if I've added correctly I got the error
quartz not found as:

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried:

1. go to target
2. expanding and double clicking.
3. now I got a window opened having linked libraries.
4. clicking on + sign.
5. now i got list of all the frameworks but "surprise not the quartzframework only quartzcore type of thing"
6. so I click on add other and navigate to system-->library-->frameworks and select quartzframework.
7. click on relative to build product and add successfully.

Now if I try to test if everything is fine I got above error. I also tried to clean all targets close Xcode but getting error.

i also try this link [go to project menu-->add to project-->systems-->library-->frameworks-->quartzframework](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pdfkit.html)

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That folder contains frameworks for OS X; Quartz is not in iOS. Quartz is just a compilation of a few other frameworks, most of which do have alternatives in iOS. PDFKit can be replicated by UIWebView for simple PDF displaying, or CGPDFDocument if you want more advanced control. QuicklookUI is available separately as Quicklook.framework with a few differences.

However, there is no equivalent of Quartz Composer in iOS, even in private frameworks. OpenGLES is pretty much your only option for 3d graphics, but don't expect the iPhone to handle something as complex as a Quartz composition would be.

And the iOS frameworks are located in

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```